# Unable to change program name in EV3 IDE

Tags: ev3

My students are having a weird problem in the EV3 IDE. When we try to change the program name, in the IDE, the name reverts to program.

As an example, if the student is creating several programs, such as `1-2`, `1-3` ... they click on the + button to create a new program. They then select that new tab named "program x." Then overwrite that word with something like `1-3` to indicate chapter one, program three.

However, after clicking on the workspace, the name of the program reverts to, `program x`.

This is not consistent, sometimes using an underscore instead of a dash works, but none of this is consistent. I would appreciate suggestions in regard to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this only happens when there is already a program with the same name.

If you start a new project and add 3 new programs named `1-1`, `1-2` and `1-3`, it works as expected. But if you try to add a 4th program named `1-1`, `1-2` or `1-3`, then the name will revert back to the default name because there is already another program with the same name.